# I've tried a couple of different methods to join this String and keep getting syntax errors. can anyone tell me what I'm doing wrong?

Tags: python, string

```
words = ['This', 'is', 'by', 'far', 'my', 'favorite', 'class', 'I', 'have', 'ever', 'taken']
sentence = .join(words)
print(sentence)

File "<ipython-input-16-1c39adcbe5ab>", line 2
    sentence = .join(words)
               ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

I've tried a couple of different methods to join this String and keep getting syntax errors. Can anyone tell me what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: `python` is a much more important tag than `string` here. Someone who knows the ins and outs of C strings or Java strings won't be of any use for a Python question; _always_ tag the programming language. Whereas "string" could really be left out -- there's not really any such thing as someone who's an expert on strings, especially in a portable / cross-language sense.

Answer (score 0):

You need a string to call `.join` on. Here, for example, you can use a space, since you're trying to create a sentence:

```py
sentence = ' '.join(words)
# Here ----^
```